# CakePhp 3 : Ajax - return array with html block

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, controller

This ajax request send two parameters x and y to a php controller :

```
           $.ajax({
              url : 'feuilles/test',
              data: {
                      x: x, y: y 
                  },
              type : 'post',
              dataType : 'json',
                success : function(res){
                   $.each(res, function(index, element) {
                      alert("index "+index + " element "+element);
                    });
                },

               error : function(result, statut, erreur){
                console.log(result);                   
               },

               complete : function(resultat, statut){
                 //"completed"
               }
           });
```

here's is the php controller :

```
public function test(){
    $x = $this->request->data['x'];
    $y = $this->request->data['y'];
    $actualFeuille = $this->request->session()->read('actualFeuille');
    $res = $actualFeuille->getListOfPossibilies(0,2);
    $this->set('res', $res);
}
```

$res get an array here's its content :

```
[
(int) 0 => (int) 1,
(int) 1 => (int) 2,
(int) 2 => (int) 3,
(int) 3 => (int) 4,
(int) 4 => (int) 5,
(int) 5 => (int) 6,
(int) 6 => (int) 7,
(int) 7 => (int) 8,
(int) 8 => (int) 9,
(int) 9 => (int) 10,
(int) 10 => (int) 11,
(int) 11 => (int) 12,
(int) 12 => (int) 13,
(int) 13 => (int) 14
]
```

When I get back the response it shows that there's an error, the fact is that the body recieved in the response html content just like the following example :

```
"<div class="cake-debug-output"> <span><strong>\src\Model\Entity\Feuille.php</strong> (line <strong>68</strong>)</span> <pre class="cake-debug"> (int) 15 </pre> </div><div class="cake-debug-output"> <span><strong>\src\Model\Entity\Feuille.php</strong> (line <strong>61</strong>)</span> <pre class="cake-debug"> [ (int) 0 =&gt; (int) 1, (int) 1 =&gt; (int) 2, (int) 2 =&gt; (int) 3, (int) 3 =&gt; (int) 4, (int) 4 =&gt; (int) 5, (int) 5 =&gt; (int) 6, (int) 6 =&gt; (int) 7, (int) 7 =&gt; (int) 8, (int) 8 =&gt; (int) 9, (int) 9 =&gt; (int) 10, (int) 10 =&gt; (int) 11, (int) 11 =&gt; (int) 12, (int) 12 =&gt; (int) 13, (int) 13 =&gt; (int) 14 ] </pre> </div>{ "res": [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ] }"
```

We can see that the body got the array in it but because of the html contained in the body it displays an error. 
My question is what to do to only get the array in the body of the response and remove all the useless html.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this by using layout `false` and autoRender `false` ? Try this below code, it may solve your problem.

```
public function test(){
    $this->layout = false;
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed in the response body, Html still there.

Comment: Have there any error, did you see in firebug in HTML tab ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to have it automatically parse I would suggest doing what the book suggest in the following links : [Routing File Extension](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions) and [Request Handler](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html)

So, just initialize the Request Handler in the app controller's initialize like this:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}
```

Then, tell your routes.php to parse the extensions like this:

```
Router::extensions(['json', 'html', 'xml']); // whatever extensions you want
```

After all this, you will want to make your ajax call url to : `feuilles/test.json` to get back the results in json.

I would also recommend serializing the results in the controller like this:

```
$this->set('res', $res);
$this->set('_serialize', ['res']);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Theasc721, what @Alimon Karim means is you have to do it like this

```
public function test(){
    $this->layout = false;
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $x = $this->request->data['x'];
    $y = $this->request->data['y'];
    $actualFeuille = $this->request->session()->read('actualFeuille');
    $res = $actualFeuille->getListOfPossibilies(0,2);
    //please make sure you are providing an array for this.
    echo json_encode($res);  
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I have applied it, with another content in the test function, here's the its content : `public function test(){
        $this->layout = false;
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $array = array("Name" => "John");
        echo json_encode($array);
        exit;
    }`

Comment: And this is the returned response I see in the error function of my ajax request when I `console.log(result)` :                                               `Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "<pre class="cake-error"><a href="javascript:void(0…dex.php, line 37</pre></div></pre>{"Name":"John"}", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}abort: (a)always: ()complete: ()done: ()error: ()fail: ()getAllResponseHeaders: ()getResponseHeader: (a)overrideMimeType: (a)pipe: ()progress: .....`

Comment: can you gist your javascript and cakephp controller code to see what is wrong with it.

Comment: I think I've figured out where the problem comes from, the problem in fact comes from the value returned from the method `getListOfPossibilies()` of the Entity `Feuille`, when I remove the line that call that method it works perfectly. Does anyone know how to fix this ?